# Why we Show encoded ampersand on HTML pages

Tags: html

Why we use `&` instead of `&amp;` ?
What is the advantage ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [HTML 4.0.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html#h-5.3.2):

> Authors should use `&amp;` (ASCII
>   decimal 38) instead of `&` to avoid
>   confusion with the beginning of a
>   character reference (entity reference
>   open delimiter). Authors should also
>   use `&amp;` in attribute values since
>   character references are allowed
>   within CDATA attribute values.

Your question should be reversed!

Answer (score 4):

You should always use `&amp;`, because that's the only way to create valid HTML.

Since the `&` character is used for entities (such as `&amp;` or `&gt;`), it must be escaped in order to write a literal &.